# Magento 1.9 customize email invoice totals

Tags: email, magento-1.9, php

I want to customize the totals part of the invoice email. The image bellow is what i get.

[image]

As you can see i get USt. and Steuer (Tax) twice. Also i need to translate one of the taxes and Grand Total (inkl. tax).

The questions are:
What files are responsible for the invoice email? (send path too)
How can i modify the invoice (even directly)?
What .csv file is responsible for the invoice translations?

Thanks

EDIT:
All right i found out where the template for the invoice is located. It's in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/invoice/items.phtml and this line of code is the totals `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('invoice_totals')?>`